# How is the best way to setup board with fields for simple game in RoR and Jquery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygame

I would like to write simple on-line game in Ruby.
For start only with single player mode.
I did some research about writing games in ruby and i found this two links:

> - https://github.com/tylerc/rog - simple game with server based on sinatra
> - http://rubygame.org - ruby game library

But im thinking this maybe is an overkill.

**Assumptions of game**

```
Turn-based game
Two players
Each player have 10 pawns
Each pawns have diferent ability(speed, armor)
Pawns moves like in Chess
Pawns can throw a ball
Board with 64 fields
```

Comment: this question is too subjective for stack overflow.  you might try asking it in chat

Answer (score 1):

Rubygames was very nice for a long time. Sadly John no longer has the time to drive it forward, and possibly not to maintain it either, which I can understand.

Gamebox was written by shawn42 (on IRC) and is still maintained, it used rubygames but then switched to Gosu instead.

At any rate, I feel we should all come together and create something that is useful for game projects in Ruby.

Let's get together and build something that is useful for everyone.

(My personal motivation is mostly to recreate the old games of the 1990 to 2000 area.)